# Getting a variable out of a list

Tags: r, vector

I make a regression and get a dataset out:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(4,15,60)

fit <- lm(x ~ y)
```

Now my fit result gives me a Intercept (1.16244) and  y-variable (0.03181) How do I reference only the y-var? I have tried to do:

```
Yvar <- c(fit[1])
```

but everything is stored in the `Yvar`. The I tried to make a vector:

```
Yvar <- as.vector(c(fit[1]))
```

Here everything get stored also. How do I get

```
Yvar = 0.03181
```

Comment: `fit$coefficients[2]`

Comment: And `coef(fit)["y"]`, as explained in `help(lm)`